# Extending array in HDF5 using PyTables

Tags: pytables

I normally use `h5py` to do the HDF5 stuff in Python and if I want to create a dataset which I want to extend later or, I do:

```
f = h5py.File('foo.h5', 'w')
d = f.create_dataset('whatever', (5, 5), maxshape=(None, 5), dtype='i8', chunks=True)
...
d.resize((23, 5))
...
```

The `maxshape(None, ...)` sets the first dimension to "infinity", so it's extensible.

Now I have a project where I need to stick with PyTables and wanted to build up large arrays step by step. Is there a way to extend `arrays` in PyTables?

This is roughly the idea:

```
import tables as tb
import numpy as np

filename = "foo.h5"
h5file = tb.File(filename, "a")

gbar = h5file.create_group(h5file.root, "bar", "Pressure")
h5file.create_array(gbar, 'left', np.array((1, 2, 3, 4)), "...")

# now extend the shape of (4,) and append more arrays iteratively???

h5file.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution in the docs: `tables.EArray`

http://www.pytables.org/usersguide/libref/homogenous_storage.html#earrayclassdescr

Here is a descriptive example code which adds two "columns" with two different ways of `dtype` definition. The `with` block can be called multiple times and it will extend the columns:

```
import tables as tb
import numpy as np

filename = 'foo.h5'

with tb.File(filename, "a") as f:        
    if "/foo" not in f:
        group = f.create_group("/", 'foo', 'Foo Information')
    else:
        group = f.root.foo

    if "col1" not in group:
        a = tb.Atom.from_dtype(np.dtype('<f8'), dflt=0.0)
        arr = f.create_earray(group, 'col1', a, (0,), "Bar")
    else:
        arr = getattr(group, "col1")

    arr.append(np.arange(10))
    arr.append(np.arange(40, 45))

    if "col2" not in group:
        b = tb.Int64Atom()
        arr = f.create_earray(group, 'col2', b, (0,), "Baz")
    else:
        arr = getattr(group, "col")

    arr.append(np.arange(7))
    arr.append(np.arange(30, 38))
```